# How to make List with WebSockets for a website on mono?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, mono, websocket, signalr

I start learning web development with C# on mono, and 
I wish to create a page which contains the list of something (items), the page should be done in the best possible level to be competitive with the other pages.

1) First I discovered .NET 1.1 classes DataGrid, DataList and Repeater
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479015.aspx
this is very old technology from 2003, which uses ViewState and full page reloads
and enthusiasts created various techniques to reduce ViewState text length

2) .Net 2.0 added DataGrid, and Callback framework
http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.2/NET_Server_Doc/developer/ADF/ajax_callback.htm
(Client Callback Manager and WebResource.axd)

3) .Net 3.5 introduces UpdatePanel (and ScriptManager class)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb386573%28v=vs.100%29.aspx
this allows to place DataGrid within UpdatePanel and almost solve the task of creating list on the web (except real-time updates and the presence of ViewState)

In the parallel path of development, ASP .NET MVC 3 was created (which done everything without viewstate by intent). And there is Grid.Mvc component for it
http://gridmvc.codeplex.com/
29 Jul 2012 - this is most recent ready to use technology which I saw for this task

4) .Net 4.5 introduces support of RFC 6455 (WebSockets)
http://www.codemag.com/Article/1210051

WebSockets was wrapped by more high-level library SignalR
http://blog.filipekberg.se/2012/12/10/running-signalr-on-mono/

I expect that there should be a list component which uses SignalR/WebSockets to dynamically update items, but I am unable to find it yet. Is there version of UpdatePanel which works over WebSocket instead of XMLHttpRequest object? Or some other list component which works with WebSockets directly?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this tutorial: [Working on JSON objects in jQuery and MVC](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/124541/Working-on-JSON-objects-in-jQuery-and-MVC)

Once you have the JSON data in the browser, you can use it in many ways with for example [jQuery widgets](http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxgrid/).

It seems that WebSockets are not yet implemented in Mono: http://go-mono.com/status/status.aspx?reference=4.5&profile=4.5&assembly=System

You can use other WebSocket frameworks in mono:

- http://vtortola.github.io/WebSocketListener/
- http://xsockets.net/
- http://alchemywebsockets.net/
- https://superwebsocket.codeplex.com/